# An absolutely continuous function which is not uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sobolev-spaces

It is [well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity) that, on a compact set, absolutely continuous (AC) implies uniformly continuous (UC). A classic example of UC not AC  is the Cantor function, which is continuous on $[0,1]$, therefore uniformly continuous, but famously not absolutely continuous.

However, I am struggling to find a function (on a noncompact set, obviously) that is **AC, but not UC**.

Any suggestion?

Comment: There is no such function. Absolute continuity implies uniform continuity. From the definition given in the Wiki page you link to, this can be seen by considering sequences comprising a single interval.

Comment: @GBA $x^{2}$ is not abolutely continuous on $\mathbb R$

Comment: @RobArthan thanks, true, sorry, that was very trivial :)

Comment: No need to apologise! We all have those moments!